# Hide/show divs for different page layouts JS issues

Tags: javascript

I have a WP page with a main div area and 2 buttons above it.

I have some JS which is meant to:

- On page load, show a list type view of posts in the main div
- When you press the 'gallery view' button, swap that main div content to the gallery view and hide the list view
- when you press the list view button, swap the main div content back to the list view and hide the gallery view
- Further pressing them continues to swap the div content

The JS I have nearly works. On page load it shows the list content. However on the first press of the gallery button, it doesn't hide the list view. But if you then press the list view button again, it works and the gallery view does get hidden and then further presses of buttons, it continues to work as it should.

It's just that first div switch where it doesn't hide the div that's the issue.

Here's the relevant JS, CSS and HTML:

JS:

```
<script>
    var _targetdiv = null;
    function showdiv(id) {
        if(_targetdiv)
            _targetdiv.style.display = 'none';
            _targetdiv = document.getElementById(id);
            _targetdiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="project-view-controls">
    <a onclick="showdiv('project-image-archive');" id="project-gallery-btn" class="project-hide-btn">Link</a>
    <a onclick="showdiv('project-list-archive');" id="project-list-btn" class="project-hide-btn">Link</a>
</div><!-- #project-view-controls -->

<div id="project-image-archive" class="hidden">
    <p>Image view view here</p>
</div><!--#project-image-archive-->

<div id="project-list-archive">
    <p>list view here</p>
</div><!--#project-list-archive-->
```

I'm not sure why it's just not working on the first instance of the button being pressed but it works after that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how are you changing the value of _targetdiv from null to div???

Comment: I should have mentioned in the OP. I'm a novice with JS and the above has been put together from some Google searches. So I don't know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I want to answer, is your question, why it is not working on the first button click. Its pretty simple, so lets have a look at your JS.

```js
var _targetdiv = null;
function showdiv(id) {
    if(_targetdiv)
        _targetdiv.style.display = 'none';
        _targetdiv = document.getElementById(id);
        _targetdiv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

First you set the _targetdiv to NULL. The first time you click on a button and your function showdiv is called. The first time you call this function your if-statement is false, cause _targetdiv is null, so your code jumps to the next line `_targetdiv = document.getElementById(id);` and execute it, so _targetdiv is now set and will be displayed. So the second time you call this function _targetdiv is still set, so it can be hidden trough your code, cause your if-statement is true.

I would change your Javascript to something like this:

```
function showdiv(obj){
    // First set both elements invisible, so nothing is displayed
    document.getElementById('project-image-archive').style.display = 'none';   
    document.getElementById('project-list-archive').style.display = 'none';   

    // Now show only the div that is requested
    document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'block';
}
```

What the Javascript now does is, it hides both elements, so that nothing is displayed and directly after that it takes the id from the given object and displays it.

I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: First off, thanks for the reply. Just tried this out however and the buttons now don't do anything? Also, I read through your notes and that helps me see what you mean about the null bit. A thought I had was, would it not make sense to have the name of the first div instead of null?

Comment: First, I edited my answer, so that it will work now. I misread something the first time and wrote some wrong code, but its fixed now and I´m really sorry for that.

The second thing is to answer your question. If you write the divs name in your original Javascript into _targetdiv instead of NULL it wouldnt work either, cause first your code tries to hide an element and then to make the requested one visible. But what should work is to do this: var _targetdiv = document.GetElementById('project-list-archive'); cause it first hides the list-view and then displays the requested view.

Comment: Yes, that works brilliantly now, thanks. I'll also have a play with your notes to help my knowledge for the future. Thanks for all the help!